# How to convert/transform in the DOM following dl dt structure to table on the fly using jQuery or d3js in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, dom

How to transform in the DOM following dl dt values to table on the fly using jQuery or d3js in a document
Rows may have any order of data elements and some missing columns too...
It feels like it requires transpose operation rows to columns

**From**

```
<div id="conatainer">
<dl class="table">
    <dt class="row">1</dt>
    <dd>
        <dl>
            <dt>name</dt>
            <dd>Tom Cruise</dd>
            <dt>age</dt>
            <dd>56</dd>
        </dl>
    </dd>
    <dt class="row">2</dt>
    <dd>
        <dl>
            <dt>dob</dt>
            <dd>April 4, 1965</dd>
            <dt>name</dt>
            <dd>Robert Downey Jr.</dd>
            <dt>age</dt>
            <dd>53</dd>
        </dl>
    </dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

**To**

```
<div id="conatainer">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>s.no</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>dob</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Tom Cruise</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Robert Downey Jr.</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>April 4, 1965</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an ID for the table and hide it initially, then use [replaceWith](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```js
$('button').click(() => {
  const newTable = $('#new-table');
  newTable.show();
  $('dl').replaceWith(newTable);

});
```

```css
dl{
  background: green
}

table{
  background: blue;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>replace</button>

<dl class="table">
    <dt class="row">1</dt>
    <dd>
        <dl>
            <dt>name</dt>
            <dd>Tom Cruise</dd>
            <dt>age</dt>
            <dd>56</dd>
        </dl>
    </dd>
    <dt class="row">2</dt>
    <dd>
        <dl>
            <dt>dob</dt>
            <dd>April 4, 1965</dd>
            <dt>name</dt>
            <dd>Robert Downey Jr.</dd>
            <dt>age</dt>
            <dd>53</dd>
        </dl>
    </dd>
</dl>

<table id='new-table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>s.no</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>dob</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Tom Cruise</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Robert Downey Jr.</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>April 4, 1965</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry I mean to transform the data dynamically from dl dt tags to table view, not just static replace sorry for my earlier title just edited to be clear